# Math: Is it possible walk a node tree and parse it using RPN?

Tags: parsing, math, mathjs

I'm working on a problem where I need to parse a string math equation, and use RPN to solve it.

Is it possible to get the tokenization step, and node tree from another library like this:
https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/parse.html

And walk the node tree and solve it with RPN?

*The reason I'm using RPN is because I'm doing some fancy stuff with percentages that I can't seem to figure out with regular infix notation.*

Comment: What do you.mean by "solve"? Do you mean "evaluate"? Or do you really mean "solve" as in "find x such that x²+3=4"? Also, why use RPN if you have a parser which produces a parse tree?

Comment: As in reduce it to one answer.